# Types of articulation

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms, joining

I am in the process of designing an off road vehicle and require a form of articulation between the front and back half and cannot find relevant information on the types of joints available.
I'm looking for movement similar to the vehicle in the video posted
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WT73uOhKSAY

Comment: One vehicle that provided drive to the trailer was Landrover so have a look especially at the military version of the forward control...

Comment: What about using electric motors to drive the wheels a-la Tesla? Electrical power is easier to pass around than mechanical power.

Comment: You could use a hydraulic motor in the rear part of the vehicle and connect to the front with flexible hydraulic tubing.

Answer (score 0):

One category of vehicle that does transmit power from the drive unit to the other unit is the agricultural tractor : have a look at the different shaft sections that have been used square, lemon (oval type) etc with the use of Hardy-Spicer or constant velocity joints for articulation.

As well as the Landrover as I mentioned above, I think there was a large truck with driven trailer in the Paris-Dakar but can't remember the manufacturer..